# How can I remove the font/icon shadow/s?

Tags: icons, fonts, gnome-panel, shadow

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, how can I remove the font/icon shadow/s?

[image: Top Panel Font Shadow]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to turn off antialiasing.

- Install `gnome-tweaks` (unless it's already installed).
- Open Tweaks and switch to Fonts.
- For Antialiasing, select "None".

Note: This change affects the desktop itself (including the top bar) and some related applications/tools.

(I wouldn't be surprised if you change your mind, and if so you can easily change it back to the default "Subpixel" option.)